# Algorithmic complexity of Python has_key

Tags: python, algorithm

Was wondering, what is the algorithmic complexity of Python dictionaries' has key method? I know the underlying structure of a dictionary is a hash map/table.

Edit: Sorry for the duplicate. Google search returned no results. Makes sense that it's O(1). I was originally wondering if you had to transverse the array of keys, but it makes sense instead you'd use the hash function to find the subsequent buckets and transverse the buckets to find the matching key pair. Thanks.

Comment: It is constant time. But you shouldn't be using this method, it was deprecated in Python 2 and was removed in Python 3. Instead of `my_dict.has_key(x)` just use `x in my_dict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dictionaries in python are implemented as hash tables (unordered maps) I assume the complexity for has_key would be O(1) on average or O(m) in worst case where m is the size of underlying hash table.